# Python interpreter embedded in the application fails to load native modules

Tags: python, c, linux

I have an application that statically links to `libpython.a` (2.7). From within the application's interpreter I try importing `time` module (`time.so`), which fails with:

```
ImportError: ./time.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_IOError
```

So, this module has unresolved symbols:

```
nm -D time.so | grep PyExc_IOError
         U PyExc_IOError
```

I figured that this symbol is discarded by the linker when linking the application. OK, I'm now linking `libpython` with all symbols:

```
... -Wl,-whole-archive -lpython -Wl,-no-whole-archive ...
```

The symbol is now there:

```
$ nm app | grep PyExc_IOError
8638348 D PyExc_IOError
08638ca0 d _PyExc_IOError
```

But I still get the same import error. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you following the steps in the embedding guide? Compiling with distutils?

Comment: @Eli, yep, it's right there. My gnat-like attention span was not enough to make it until the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides making sure all of libpython is included in your binary, you also need to make sure the symbols in the library are exposed to shared objects being loaded. When you're linking libpython (statically) into your main binary this means you need the `--export-dynamic` linker argument (so `-Wl,--export-dynamic` or `-Xlinker --export-dynamic` as the gcc argument.) When loading a shared object with libpython (say, when you embed libpython into a plugin for your app) this means you have to make sure the shared object is loaded with the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag to `dlopen()`.