# Issue with SFCB, the python-binding layer and python providers in ESX 4.0

Tags: python-3.x, python-extensions, python-embedding, esx, authorize.net-cim

We are writing SFCB providers in python, Since SFCB talks to only C++ providers we need to have an intermediate layer(cmpi-bindings, a python extension module) which can talk to SFCB and start the provider when needed.

The same cmpi layer is working completely fine (i.e. reading SFCB call and then running the python provider)when it is run on ESX 4.1, but on ESX 4.0 it fails to import python modules.

After some debugging I found that import datetime module is failing with the unresolved symbol  (PyExc_IOError) errror. I tried to build those module with -XLinker --exportdynamic so that they look for the those unresolved symbol as suggested in [Python interpreter embedded in the application fails to load native modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223312/python-interpreter-embedded-in-the-application-fails-to-load-native-modules) , but went in vain.

What are the options I can try next. ( since the same code base is working for 4.1 but not 4.0). Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: It seems that this is not an issue between ESX and SFCB Python providers at all, but that the problem is that the datetime module fails to find certain symbols when you are embedding Python. Is this correct? In that case you should change the title.

Comment: Yep but happening only in ESX 4.0, with 4.1 its absolutely fine. that is the main case here

Comment: Yeah, but there can be several different reasons for that, many which would have nothing to do with ESX.

Comment: that is exactly where i want to go, I need to find out what and when and I need some pointers for that, so what ever the reasons ( which you think )are there, bring to the discussion.

Comment: I think the exact traceback and a more useful topic would help. It's probably best to close this question and make a new one. ESX may be relevant. I'm pretty sure this is in absolutely no way a problem with SFCB, even though I have no idea what that is. (Which you also don't explain).